# Determinant of generator of SU(2)

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, determinant, lie-algebras

My lecture notes use the following arguments in the start of deriving the generators of $SU(2)$.

Let $U = I + T + O(T^2)$.

$U^\dagger U = I + T + T^\dagger + O(T^2) = 1 \implies T = - T^\dagger $

$det(U) = 1 + tr(T) + O(T^2) = 1$

I do not understand the last line, where does this come from and why is there no mention of $det(T)$?

I've seen a formula on another question that makes me think it should be $det(U) = det(I + T + O(T^2)) = 1 + det(T) + tr(T) = O(T^2)$ but I don't know if it is implicit that $det(T) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

If $T = \epsilon M$ for some 2x2 matrix $M$ of order 1, then $tr(T) = O(\epsilon) = O(T)$ but $det(T) = O(\epsilon^2) = O(T^2)$, therefore the above lines are correct.